# Remove everything but numbers and spaces in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression that currently matches any non-numeric characters:

```
var.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z ]/,'');
```

I now need to keep the spaces as well as numbers, but I am having difficulty modifying this.

Any help?

Comment: What you have doesn't keep spaces and numbers?

Comment: Your regex does not match "any non-numeric characters"; it doesn't match alphabetic characters.

Comment: your regex matches none alpha-numeric characters .. not only numeric characters

Comment: @Rohit Jain - I have been trying things, that is why the regex is almost complete, but I apologise for not being the JavaScript guru you expect me to be.

Comment: [^0-9\s] this will do it .. this will match every thing that is not a number or space

Comment: Thanks everyone, I see. What I have keeps numbers only. It is validating a phone number and I would like to keep spaces for area codes. E.g. 01904 123456

Comment: @Jon. I didn't expect you to be a Javascript guru. No  one on SO expects this from question askers. We just want you to be good learners, and try out your problem first on your own, so that you can learn from your mistakes.

Comment: I have tried it out on my own. As I mentioned before, I got 99% of the way with no luck. I have given my attempt and decided to ask others. This wasn't a 5 minute attempt. Thanks @codeiz that's perfect, if you want to put it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is a regular expression that will match every thing that is not a number or a space ..

```
[^0-9\s]
```

explanation 
hey regex engine :

1- match every thing .

2- `^` --> that's not

3- `0-9` --> a number

4- `\s` --> and a space